# How to remotely set another command on cooldown when i do another command || Discord py

Tags: python, discord.py

Is it possible so when i do a command, some other commands also get the cooldown? if it is possible, how to do it?

(like when i do **!command1** i cant do **!command2** until the cooldown of command1 done)

example of what thing i want to do:

```
@bot.command()
@commands.cooldown(1, 10, commands.BucketType.user)
async def command1(ctx):
  @command2.set_cooldown(ctx)

@bot.command()
@commands.cooldown(1, 10, commands.BucketType.user)
async def command2(ctx):
  @command1.set_cooldown(ctx)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set a cooldown after the command is defined you have to mess a bit with the internal attributes, here's an example how to add *and remove* a cooldown after command creation (it depends from version to version, this example works on discord.py 1.7.3)

```py
@bot.command()
async def command_to_add_cooldown(ctx):
   ...


@bot.command()
async def add_cooldown(ctx):
    rate, per, bucket_type = 1, 60.0, commands.BucketType.user  # cooldown settings
    cooldown_mapping = commands.CooldownMapping.from_cooldown(rate, per, bucket_type)
    command_to_add_cooldown._buckets = cooldown_mapping
    await ctx.send("Added cooldown")


@bot.command()
async def remove_cooldown(ctx):
    cooldown_mapping = commands.CooldownMapping(None)
    command_to_add_cooldown._buckets = cooldown_mapping
    await ctx.send("Removed cooldown")
```

Comment: lemme try first :) thanks for answer btw

Comment: the add_cooldown one doesn't work, why?

Comment: It works, the issue is that the cooldown was just applied, so when you use right afterwards the cooldown is not effected since it was just applied, at the second time you’ll have the cooldown

Comment: lemme try again

Comment: wait, do u mean i should do the command twice or what

Comment: yes, I mean that

Comment: nope, stil not work

Comment: what discord.py version are you using? are you getting any errors? telling me it doesn’t work it’s too broad for me to be able to help you…

Comment: 1. the newest
2. well, it just doesn't let me have the cooldown

Comment: the newest version on pypi or github?

Comment: i guess the one from pypi

Comment: actually imma accept this answer first, i'll wait for update tho :V