# Discord.py - Set a command cooldown using the command's arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py, arguments

I have a discord bot and I am trying to make a command that gives you a certain amount of cash depending on the time you wait.
Think of it like going on a quest in a game, where the 12-hour quest gives more than the 6-hour one, which gives more than the 3-hour one, and so on.

So to do this, I tried setting the command cooldown to the time specified when a user uses the command.
Like so ('time' is the specified quest length in hours):

```
@bot.command("quest")
@commands.cooldown(1, time*60*60, commands.BucketType.user)
async def quest(ctx, time):
    ...
```

Obviously I got an error saying that the variable time is not defined.
I tried searching for an answer but I couldn't find anything.

How can I use the command argument ('time') for the command cooldown?

Comment: you could make a global variable of when the command was last used, and when it is used again use the difference between now and when it was last used to calculate how much money to award the user

Comment: Not exactly a duplicate but really similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71375279/how-to-remotely-set-another-command-on-cooldown-when-i-do-another-command-dis/71381061

Comment: `cooldowns` aren't the way to go about this. One, they will be reset if your bot ever restarts as it stores it in memory. I would recommend doing a database which can store a `datetime.datetime` then you could take the current time and add `datetime.timedelta(hours=3|6|9)`, depending on the hours the quest is for, then when user tries it again, check `if current time > stored_time`, if not, you can get remaining time with `stored_time - current_time`, and use `humanize.precisedela()` on it to make the obtained `timedelta` into a readable format. humanize is an external package